# can't update meteor users collection using graphql mutation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs, graphql

I have a problem with my project using react meteor and graphql. I try to insert users collection by `Account.createUser()` function in resolvers mutation as picture below, but it didn't work, when I call mutation nothing change.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S40jk.png) is my schema

And here [my mutation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyp7P.png)

Comment: Would you add your portion of codes so it would be easier ti solve your problem

Comment: this is my picture of schema: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S40jk.png

Comment: and this is my picture of mutation: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyp7P.png)

Comment: when i use console.log() to print value of user it return true value just Account.createUser() is interrupt

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
emails:[{adress:'example@example.com', verified:false}]
```

Comment: but when i put  Accounts.createUser() fuction into react render() it still work